# Question regarding eigenvalue for left shift operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am asked whether if $|\lambda|=1$ is an eigenvalue for the left shift operator $T:\ell^{p}\rightarrow\ell^{p}$ for $1\leq p<\infty$ where $T(x_1,x_2,\dots)=(x_2,x_3,\dots)$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ My intuition says no, $|\lambda|=1$ cannot be an eigenvalue for $T$. Because

$$Tx-\lambda x=(x_2-\lambda x_1,x_3-\lambda x_2,\dots)=0$$

from which we can see that $x_2=\lambda x_1,\ x_3=\lambda^2 x_1$ etc.

From this I would get that an eigenvector would be $(\lambda,\lambda^2,\dots)$. If $|\lambda|=1$ then this supposed eigenvector does not exist in $\ell^p$ since the norm of the supposed eigenvector is infinite. It's only an eigenvector if $|\lambda|<1$.

Is this correct? And if so, could I argue/show this in a more clever way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are correct and argument is neat. There is no better argument. But there is a small typo: $x_3=\lambda^{2}x_1$, not $\lambda^{2}x_2$

Comment: Great, thanks for the reply! Oh yeah, sorry, I'll fix that.