# Question about Eigenvalues of left shift on $l^\infty$.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Question about Eigenvalues of left shift $S_L $on $l^\infty$.

I showed that $\lambda =1 $ is not eigenvalue for $S_L$ on $l^1$ but I could solve for this for on $l^\infty$.

Let me also write how did I find $\lambda=1$ is not eigenvalue on $l^1$. Actually, one way is directly $Ker(S_L)=\{ \emptyset \}$ or using $S_L (x) = \lambda.x$

In second way, I used $l^1$ property to have convergency. My question is how can I approach for $l^\infty$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $l^\infty$ of what?  $l^\infty(\Bbb{N})$?  $l^\infty(\Bbb{Z})$?  Of a finite set?  On $\Bbb{N}$ and $\Bbb{Z}$ I think the constant sequence $1$ is an eigenvector of the left shift with eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: It is stated like this. Just $l^\infty$ and I didn't catch how do you obtain this?

Comment: He is asking what space each of the $x_n$ of $(x_n) \in l^\infty$ belongs to. Are they sequences of real numbers, integers?

Comment: Okay, it should be real sequences.

Comment: @Fuat Ray: What don't you catch?  Why if you shift left the constant sequence $1$ with index set $\Bbb{N}$ or index set $\Bbb{Z}$ you get the same sequence?

Comment: @0XLR: I was asking whether the index set for $n$ in your notation is $\Bbb{N}$ or $\Bbb{Z}$ or a finite set.

Comment: @JohnDoe It is definitely not a finite set for sure because sequence spaces generally consider countable sequences as elements.

Comment: So your claim is $\lambda =1$ is an eigenvalue and constant sequence $1$ is its eigenvector. How did you decide $1$ is an eigenvalue?

Comment: @FuatRay: If $(x_n)$ is the constant sequence $1$ then $S_L((x_n)) = (x_n) = 1\cdot (x_n)$.  That's how.

Comment: Ahhh, you are right. Thanks to you it seems to straightforward, right?

Comment: In fact each value in the interval $[-1, 1]$ should be an eigenvalue. I will try to produce an answer showing this.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3450337/question-regarding-eigenvalue-for-left-shift-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the space you are focusing on is the standard sequence space of all bounded real sequences:
$$
l^\infty(\mathbb R) = \{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N} : \sup_n |x_n| < \infty\}
$$ I will show that every $\lambda \in [-1, 1]$ is an eigenvalue of $S_L$ and also that **values outside that range cannot be eigenvalues**.

Notice the following. If $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ is an eigenvalue of the left shift operator $S_L : l^\infty(\mathbb R) \to l^\infty(\mathbb R)$, which is explicitly given by: $S_L[(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}] = (x_{n + 1})_{n \in \mathbb N}$, then that means there is non-zero $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ s.t.
$$
S_L[(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}] = \lambda (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \implies (x_{n + 1})_{n \in \mathbb N} = (\lambda x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}
$$ In other words for all $n \in \mathbb N$
$$
x_{n + 1} = \lambda x_n \implies x_{n} = \lambda^{n}x_0
$$ Now we can see what conditions $\lambda$ must satisfy:

First, since $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is non-zero, $x_0$ can't be zero otherwise by the above all values would be zero. Hence $|\lambda| > 1$ is impossible. Otherwise as  $|x_0| >  0$, $|x_n| = |\lambda|^n |x_0|$ grows arbitrarily large so that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ would fail to be a bounded sequence i.e. it won't be in $l^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

In other words, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, $\lambda \in [-1, 1]$ necessarily. And in fact, each value in $[-1, 1]$ is an eigenvalue. Clearly $1$ is an eigenvalue with prototypical eigenvector $(1)_{n \in \mathbb N}$. And $-1$ is an eigenvalue with prototypical eigenvector $((-1)^n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$. Do you see why each $-1 < \lambda < 1$ is an eigenvalue?

Comment: Yes, because series would be convergent by geometric series test.